# Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку

Tags: c#

> ```
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "DTAPINET, Version=4.7.3.136, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f326389dc760240" или один из зависимых от них компонентов.
> ```

Не удалось запустить приложение, поскольку его параллельная конфигурация неправильна. Дополнительные сведения содержатся в журнале событий приложений. (Исключение из `HRESULT: 0x800736B1`)
Имя файла: "`DTAPINET, Version=4.7.3.136, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f326389dc760240" ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800736B1)`: Не удалось запустить приложение, поскольку его параллельная конфигурация неправильна. Дополнительные сведения содержатся в журнале событий приложений. (Исключение из `HRESULT: 0x800736B1`)

```
   в DtLoop.Device..ctor()
   в DtLoop.DtLoop.DtLoop_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Товарищи подскажите как эту ошибку победить!!

Comment: 1. А есть ли такая сборка в каталоге, откуда стартует программа? Если нет, только вы сами можете себе помочь, мы за вас её туда не скопируем.
2. Из вашего stack trace'а видно, что у вас модельная функциональность реализована во View. Не делайте так, разбейте честно на архитектурные уровни.
3. Для отладки проблем с загрузкой используйте FusionLog в Exception'е. (Покопайтесь, он там должен быть.)

Comment: Да сборка присутствует!! Перепробовано много методов которые предложил google. Разворачиваю программу на win server выдает эту ошибку,  на win 7 все работает. Платформа и все зависимости установлены !! Но не пойму откуда "ноги растут" у этой ошибки.

Comment: @IGOR: `COMException`? Посмотрите, не используете ли вы COM-компоненты (может быть, косвенно). Может, вы забыли regsvr? (Или запустили это не от админского экаунта?) Посмотрите на зависимости вашей сборки (depends.exe), чего не хватает? Может, вы собираете не ту конфигурацию.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в том FrameWork 2.0 на сервере 2008 нельзя удалить и переустановить тоже не давал,и он не мог открыть мою библиотеку  версии сборки 2.0 проблема решилась переписал библиотеку на на 4.0 и установил FrameWork 4.0 все заработало!!